# Get rid of B for (A-B)/(C-A+B)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, fractions

Is it possible to get rid of B:
$$\frac{A-B}{C-A+B} $$
**A, B, C are all non-negative.**

Comment: Well, no.  The expression clearly depends on $B$.

Comment: $ \frac{A-B}{C-A+B} = -1/(1-\frac{C}{A-B}).$

Answer (score 1):

There is no way  to get rid of $B$ in  $$\frac {A-B}{C-A+B}$$ and get an equivalent expression.

We can simplify a fraction if there is a common factor in the top and bottom of the fraction.

Here $B$ is not a factor and stays as it is in both top and bottom of your fraction.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{A-B}{C-(A-B)} = \left(\frac{C -(A-B)}{A-B}\right)^{-1}= \left(\frac{C}{A-B} - 1\right)^{-1}
$$

so you only need the quantities $C$ and $A-B$. This obviously still depends on $B$ even if only through $A-B$.

Diffferent problem:  Consider the possible values as $A,B,C$ range over all nonnegative integers.

If $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary nonnegative integers, then $A-B$ will be an arbitrary integer.

So you get $\left(\dfrac{C}{Z} - 1\right)^{-1}$ where $C$ is an arbitrary nonnegative integer and $Z$ is an arbitrary integer.

You can put $\dfrac{-C}{-Z}$ without changing the result so in fact you can get the same possible results by allowing all integers for both $C$ and $Z$.

$$
\left(\frac{C-Z}{Z}\right)^{-1} = \frac{Z}{C-Z}
$$

By shifting $C$ by $Z$ we get arbitrary rational numbers because we have arbitrary integers on both the top and bottom.

Comment: To have the parentheses look correct, use `\left(` and `\right)`.